# How to run Cassandra (cqlsh) from anywhere

Tags: linux, cassandra, cqlsh

In Cassandra the official documentation (https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/GettingStarted) it states, to start the service use

```
'bin/cassandra -f'
```

Then use

```
'bin/cqlsh'
```

to access. But to use cqlsh in this way I always have to go to the bin folder. What is the procedure to make it work such that I can type 'cqlsh' from anywhere in the console to access (not have to be in the bin folder of Cassandra setup) ?

(just like we access python directly from anywhere by just typing python3 in console )

Comment: Which Linux version do you use and how did you install Cassandra?

Comment: Linux 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64  and Installed cassandra following the steps in https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/GettingStarted

Comment: I'm pretty sure jny was inquiring as to which *flavor* of Linux you are running (Ubuntu, CentOS, etc...).  The kernel version really doesn't affect the install process.

Comment: sorry my bad, its ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get this work work, you have to add your Cassandra `bin` directory to your `$PATH`.

From a terminal prompt, check the contents of your `$PATH`.

```
$ echo $PATH
```

On my Ubuntu VM, this is what I see:

```
/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45/bin
```

Since you mention Python3, I'll check the location of that on my system as well:

```
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

As you can see, Python3 is in my `/usr/bin` directory, and `/usr/bin` is in my `$PATH`, which is why simply typing `python3` works for me (and you as well).

There are a few ways to get your Cassandra `bin` directory into your `$PATH`.  There is some debate about which is the "correct" way to do accomplish this.  So in lieu of telling you how *I* would do it, I will provide a link to a question on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) that details something like 3 ways to add a directory into your `$PATH`: [How to add a directory to my path?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path)

Answer (score 0):

Use `cassandra -f` in your root folder and then you should be able to use `cqlsh` anywhere you have cassandra installed

Comment: yes did that (that step was mentioned in the above link) but then has to be inside bin folder to execute cqlsh.

Comment: @EshanM.Herath I got the impression from your question that you did cassandra -f in the bin folder not your root folder. Are you saying you already tried running cassandra -f in root?