# Execute cqlsh inside script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cqlsh

I am trying to execute cqlsh inside bash script. My script is below. When ı try to execute sh file, it returns cql command not found

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

cqlsh -e "SELECT * FROM msg.msg_log limit 1;" > /home/yunus/sh/cqlshcontrol.txt

error1=$( more /home/yunus/sh/cqlshcontrol.txt | wc -l )

if [ $error1 -lt 1 ]; then

curl -S -X POST --data "payload={\"text\": \" Cqlsh not responding, Connection Problem   \",\"username\":\"Elevate Cassandra1\",\"icon_emoji\":\"${SLACK_ICON}\"}" https://hooks.slack.com/services/

fi
```

Comment: where is the location of python ?

Comment: /usr/bin/python

Comment: /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib64/python2.7 /etc/python /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz

Comment: Tell if this  help u : 
[1]:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944484/how-to-run-cassandra-cqlsh-from-anywhere

Answer (score 1):

## some suggestions

1. use `[[`/`]]` over `[`/`]`.
2. the return value of `$()` is not an error value and should be named `lines` or something more meaningful.  The lack of another error variable in the code makes the appended number (the `1` in `error1`) seem even odder.
3. There's no reason to use `more` or pipe inside of that subshell.  Just run `wc -l` on your file.
4. Are you sure `cqlsh` is in the `PATH`?  Try `which cqlsh` to find it.
5. `wc` will never return a negative value so comparing for equality with zero would be clear and cover just as many potential cases.

### otherwise

If that doesn't get you out of your confusion please show the output when you try to run it.